# How to count datapoints in a JSON file with expressions in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

I load a JSON file with expressions in after effects. I need to know the number of datapoints  in that JSON file for further processing.

How can i count (or index?) Them with expressions?

Comment: Can you share the json file, or a dummy version of it? And an example of what you need to extract from the file?